# from javascript two arrays to php variables and values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

on js side I have two arrays

```
arra = ['what', 'when', 'why'];

arrb = ['sea', 'tomorrow', 'because of sun'];
```

In reality the arrays are much longer.

what is the shortest (jquery) way  to get this on php side:

```
echo $what; // result: sea

echo $when;  // result: tomorrow

echo $why;  //  result: because of sun
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you want to send the js variables to the backend, you can use ajax or do the classic post and/or get.

Comment: @Eddie, of course it should be done via ajax but how to cross two arrays to get `var name / var value` pairs.

Comment: you can parse arrays as simple as any variable. There is no difference. It all comes down to how you want to use/access the array afterwards. For instance, once the array has been parsed and retrieved as a PHP variable, you can then choose to perform an `explode()` on the array to get the individual indexes, or use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object whose keys are the values from `arra` and values come from `arrb`. Then pass that as the `data` option in `$.ajax()`.

```
var dataObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    dataObj[arra[i]] = arrb[i];
}
$.ajax({
    url: "yourscript.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataObj
});
```

Then in PHP these will be in the `$_POST` array.

```
$what = $_POST['what'];
$when = $_POST['when'];
$why = $_POST['why'];
```

or more generally:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value<br>";
}
```

Comment: I would probably suggest a more general, automated way of handling the array. Manually calling each index can become rather problematic depending on the situation.

Comment: @Martin, is `foreach` part what you mean?

Comment: @puerto any loop format that would be able to run through the array, and yes, `foreach()` is one method. It just makes for a better solution, because in cases where data gets bigger, it will be a way better approach. Now, in simple situations, such as the one presented here, calling each individual index is fine, but learning about the more automated process will be more beneficial to OP in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use AJAX to `POST` the variables to a given page that you define in the URL declaration of the AJAX function.

Example of AJAX function:

```
<script>
arra = ['what', 'when', 'why'];
arrb = ['sea', 'tomorrow', 'because of sun'];

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "your_file.php",
    data : {
            arra : arra
            arrab : arrab
    },
    success: function (html) {
        //Success handling
        //do something on success
    }
})
</script>
```

Upon executing this AJAX code (how you call it is up to you), you will parse your arrays as a `POST` variable that can now be handled through PHP.

```
<?php
$arra = $_POST['arra'];
$arrb = $_POST['arrb'];
?>
```

You now have multiple ways to handle your arrays, depending on what you want to do with them.

One way is to loop through the array, and retrieve each index. `foreach()`, `for()`, `while()` as examples.

```
<?php
foreach ($arra as $key => $value) {
    echo 'value: '.$value.'<br>';
}
?>

<?php
foreach ($arrb as $key => $value) {
    echo 'value: '.$value.'<br>';
}
?>
```

In small cases, such as the one you are facing, you can generally access each array index individually as well.

```
<?php
$what = $arra['what'];
$when = $arra['when'];
$why = $arra['why'];

$sea = $arrb['sea'];
$tomorrow = $arrb['tomorrow'];
$because_of_sun = $arrb['because of sun'];
?>
```

However, I find this as general bad practice, as you'd rather use more automated solutions, since it would be your preferred approach with larger data.

Another way of parsing data would be through a `GET` method. The PHP approach will be the same, except instead of using `$_POST` to retrieve your data, you will have to use `$_GET`. Also note that `GET` variables will be visible in the URL, while `POST` variables will not.